# How Can I define Array in Python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to move from TCL to Python. I want to know how can I define an Array similar to TCL in Python?
Example:

```
set my_var(1)  "0 1 2 3 4 5 6"    
set my_var(2)  "a v g l k y p"    
set my_var(3)  "a1 a2 d1 d3 g1 p2 tr"   
.
.
.
puts "$my_var(3)"
```

Thanks,
Nelson

Comment: Here you go; https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html. And here are all DataType possibilities out of the Standard Libraries; https://docs.python.org/2/library/datatypes.html

Comment: Well start with this: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/

Answer (score 4):

I think you are after what is called a `list` in Python.

```
my_var = ['0 1 2 3 4 5 6', 'a v g l k y p', 'a1 a2 d1 d3 g1 p2 tr']

>>> my_var[2]
'a1 a2 d1 d3 g1 p2 tr'
```

Answer (score 3):

In python , you can create `lists` , which may be similar to the `arrays` in TCL.

Examples of lists -

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
print(l)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
for x in l:
    print(x)
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
print(l[0])
1
l[0] = 10
print(l[0])
10
```

Using the `for` loop above, we iterated over each element of the list and printed it.

More details on list - https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists

Answer (score 1):

[Arrays](https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html) can be set up like this, they are called lists in Python.

```
var = ['1,2,3,4', 'a,b,c', 'a1,a2,a3']
>>var[0]
'1,2,3,4'
```